# How to Parse Json from UrI to list on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, json, web-services, xamarin.android

I tried too many but no success

this is my method to get JSON string from web service Uri and deserialize it to list, and I want to use it on Xamarin Android App

```
public async void DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        string url = "http://myWebSite.com/jWebService.asmx/GetOffersJSON?storeID=2";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Task <string> downloadTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        string content = await downloadTask;

        // de-serializing json response into list
        JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(content);
        IList<JToken> results = jsonResponse["offs"].ToList();
        foreach (JToken token in results)
        {
            offers poi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<offers>(token.ToString());
            offs.Add(poi);
        }
    }
```

when I call DownloadDataAsync(); I get an error:

> An unhandled exception occured.

what is the solution?

I've parameter on my web service method, who can I deal with it?

Here is my JSON Uri result:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with 
it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"ItemID":20,"ItemBarcode":"111","ItemName":"hgh","ItemImage":"MegaOrders22017-04-14-08-34-27.jpg","ItemPrice":7.0000,"ItemNotes":"gffgdfj","OfferOn":true},{"ItemID":21,"ItemBarcode":"222","ItemName":"Nod","ItemImage":"MegaOrders22017-04-14-08-34-57.jpg","ItemPrice":4.0000,"ItemNotes":"kkkkkk","OfferOn":true},{"ItemID":22,"ItemBarcode":"333","ItemName":"kjkjkjkj","ItemImage":"MegaOrders22017-04-14-08-35-21.jpg","ItemPrice":6.0000,"ItemNotes":"hhhhggggg","OfferOn":true},{"ItemID":23,"ItemBarcode":"4444","ItemName":"oioioio","ItemImage":"MegaOrders22017-04-14-08-35-50.jpg","ItemPrice":5.0000,"ItemNotes":"hjhgfdfghj","OfferOn":true}]
</string>
```

the Class I used:

```
public class offers
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemBarcode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemImage { get; set; }
    public double ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string ItemNotes { get; set; }
    public bool OfferOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error should have more details like a stack trace where your method failed.

Comment: unfortunately, just this error text appear to me, can you tell me about the code is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 public async void DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "http://myWebSite.com/jWebService.asmx/GetOffersJSON?storeID=2";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            // de-serializing json response into list, with filtering before
            var startPosition = content.IndexOf('>') + 1;
            var endPosition = content.LastIndexOf("</", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var filteredResponseCharArray = new char[endPosition - startPosition];
            content.CopyTo(startPosition, filteredResponseCharArray, 0, endPosition - startPosition);
            var listOfOffers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<offers>>(new string(filteredResponseCharArray));
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

You should change your web service to get a valid JSON response without XML structure.

Comment: I used try-catch as your sample code but same error, I afraid the error occurs when I call the method, this is my calling: private void BtnDownload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs { DownloadDataAsync(); }

Comment: Your JSON response looks strange. Your respoonse has a XML header, but a JSON body. I think, you first should change this in your web service.If you are done with that, you don't have to filter your response in your xamarin app. I'm pretty sure, that the exception is thrown by the JsonConvert, because you have filtered your response wrong.

Comment: Thank you Sean Stayn for your reaction, I comment all the code and just keep first three lines and when I comment this line [var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);] there is no error but when I return it the error appear again, I tired from this error please I want solution

Comment: Are you sure, that your url is right? You can try to use the WebClient instead of the HttpClient: var webClient = new WebClient();
            var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);

Comment: the same error appears to me when I write this line [var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);] I think that the error is related to the Internet connection, how can I send to you the project to solve this problem please, because it is very necessary for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142104/discussion-between-sean-stayn-and-khaledalmolaa).